# Removing -copy files OneDrive created

Tags: microsoft-office, sync, office365, onedrive

I had OneDrive disabled on my computer for a while. Today, I activated it for a while and it started syncing certain folders and one of those folders contains the code for an application I'm working on.

When I noticed it, I stopped OneDrive but now I have a whole bunch of files that end with `-copy` in their name. I assume OneDrive sync process creates duplicate files that it processes and I suspect it automatically removes them at the end.

I will not go through with the sync process. Is there an easy way to remove these `-copy` files?

BTW, my Office apps are through my Office 365 subscription for my business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to delete the local `-copy` files from your computer, or the ones in OneDrive cloud?

for local files in your harddrive, you can do the following:

1. in windows explorer, go to your OneDrive folder
2. then in the search box (top-right) type in `*-copy.*`
3. explorer will search for all the `-copy` files show a list
4. click on a file and press `Ctrl+A` to select all files
5. then press `Delete` key to delete them

Answer (score 0):

I put one drive on my laptop and I think it made a copy of every file!!

Your method was working for a while and then all of sudden it stopped finding any files - and I know there are plenty. I tried both copy and Copy but it just stopped working
Any advice
Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1089414)